# Running a .net core app with EFCore from System.Diagnostics.Process fails when not using shell execute

Tags: c#, windows, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core executable build in .net 7.  this app uses entity framework core 7 underneath.
this executable runs fine from a cmd line prompt.

I have a second windows forms administration GUI project that I'd like to use to run the first executable, and capture the output of the stdout/stderr.

to do this, I create a ProcessStartInfo structure, and  set UseShellExecute to false, and override the appropriate OutputDataRecieved, ErrorDataReeceived eventhandlers.

when I start the first process without shell execute, I get a System.Configuration.Management dll 5.0.0.0 can not be found exception coming out of EFCore.  The problem goes away if I set UseShellExecute to true, but in this way I can't capture the output.

Would anyone know what the difference in GAC/Assembly lookup between using shell execute and without?  And how I can get same behavior across the two?

Comment: Is the required dll colocated with the executable, or is it in your system path somewhere? If the former, you may need to set the working directory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory?view=net-7.0#system-diagnostics-processstartinfo-workingdirectory

Comment: the required dll is in the system path somewhere.  I already set the working path to the app directory.

Comment: EF Core has *nothing* to do with `Process.Start`. .NET Core doesn't use the GAC.`System.Configuration.Management` is *NOT* used by .NET Core either, it exists only as a legacy wrapper for .NET Framework configuration files.  Post your actual code and actual error.

Comment: Finally, a .NET 7 application wouldn't reference a 5.0 assembly. I suspect your application mixes up .NET Framework and .NET Core libraries and probably doesn't use EF Core at all, but the old Entity Framework 5

Answer (score -1):

I've down a workaround by launching cmd.exe instead.
in the arguments I use the /C .

this allows me to have exact environment as starting the executable from cmdline, while still being able to turn off shell execute on the ProcessStartInfo parameters, thus allowing the capture of stdout/stderr.

Comment: You don't need `cmd` at all. Neither does EF Core have anything to do with how applications are launched. `this allows me to have exact environment as starting the executable from cmdline` no it doesn't, but it does mean that your *application* fails due to differences in environment variables eg due to differences in the PATH